# What is the total X,Y coordinate on a grid called?

Tags: terminology, discrete-mathematics

Say I have a grid that is 4 columns wide, 4 rows high, I can get the "total" number of a certain point like this:

`(y * width) + x`

So point (0,1) would be calculated like this `(1 * 4) + 0 = 4`

But does that have some kind of fancy name, something I could use in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting points in your grid according to the values of the function $(x, y)\mapsto y\cdot\mathrm{width} + x$ is commonly called *lexicographic order* or *dictionary order*, since it yields the same order you would get if you sorted the ordered pairs (0, 0), (0, 1), ..., (3, 2), (3, 3) as though they were words in a dictionary.  A function which maps one set into a total order is often called a *sort key* (in programming) or a *linear extension* (especially in order theory).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!